# Export visualization data using Qlik Engine JSON API

Tags: javascript, python, json, websocket, qliksense

Our organization uses Qlik Sense Enterprise and we are looking to automate the download process of the data used for visualizations (format can be excel or csv) instead of the manual process which leads to the following (cropped screenshot shown):

[image: From qlik sense portal]

For our use case, lets assume there is only one app which has one sheet inside and that sheet has 3 visualizations.

I have written a python script which currently has been connected to the localhost and I am able to retrieve the app_id, sheet_id and the id of the 3 charts present using Qlik Engine JSON API. The code works in the following manner:

1. Fetch the doc_list (app_list)
2. Select the app, since we have only one app we choose index as 0
3. Create a session object (I saw Qlik Engine on Dev Hub exhibiting this behavior which is why I executed this step)
4. Get the layout of the app
5. Select the sheet, since we have one sheet we choose index as 0
6. Iterate through the visualizations and print their names

I have provided the code below for your reference as well as the pastebin link can be accessed [here](https://pastebin.com/VdDBMzAJ)

```
import requests
import websocket, ssl
import json,  csv
import os, time
from pprint import pprint 
 
#Connecting to the server. The lines below will be replaced by the certificates and headers for enterprise usage later
ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("ws://localhost:4848/app/")
 
#For getting the doc (app) list
doclist_req = {
    "handle": -1,
    "method": "GetDocList",
    "params": [],
    "outKey": -1,
    "id": 1
}
 
ws.send(json.dumps(doclist_req))
result = ws.recv()
ws.send(json.dumps(doclist_req))
result = ws.recv()
result_json = json.loads(result)
print(result_json)
print()
 
#For opening the doc (app)
app_req = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "OpenDoc",
    "handle": -1,
    "params": [
        #Can iterate if multiple apps are there
        #Since only one app was present we used the index 0
        result_json['result']['qDocList'][0]['qDocId']
    ],
    "outKey": -1,
    "id": 2
}
 
#The first call seems to be for establishing the connection and second to actually send the request body
ws.send(json.dumps(app_req))
result = ws.recv()
ws.send(json.dumps(app_req))
result = ws.recv()
result_json = json.loads(result)
print(result_json)
print()
app_req_handle = result_json['result']['qReturn']['qHandle']
 
#For creating the session object necessary for fetching dimensions, fields, etc.
session_req = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "CreateSessionObject",
    "handle": app_req_handle,
    "params": [
        {
            "qInfo": {
                "qType": "SheetList"
            },
            "qAppObjectListDef": {
                "qType": "sheet",
                "qData": {
                    "title": "/qMetaDef/title",
                    "description": "/qMetaDef/description",
                    "thumbnail": "/thumbnail",
                    "cells": "/cells",
                    "rank": "/rank",
                    "columns": "/columns",
                    "rows": "/rows"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outKey": -1,
    "id": 3
}
 
ws.send(json.dumps(session_req))
result = ws.recv()
ws.send(json.dumps(session_req))
result = ws.recv()
result_json = json.loads(result)
print(result_json)
print()
session_req_handle = result_json['result']['qReturn']['qHandle']
 
#For fetching the layout of the sheets
layout_req = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "GetLayout",
    "handle": session_req_handle,
    "params": [],
    "outKey": -1,
    "id": 4
}
 
ws.send(json.dumps(layout_req))
result = ws.recv()
ws.send(json.dumps(layout_req))
result = ws.recv()
result_json = json.loads(result)
print(result_json)
print()
 
#Since only one sheet was present we used the index 0
list_of_charts = result_json['result']['qLayout']['qAppObjectList']['qItems'][0]['qData']['cells']
for chart in list_of_charts:
    print(chart['name'])
print()
 
ws.close()
```

I have explored a lot of pages on the Qlik community as well as SO and ExportData seems to be the way to go but I am not able to write the correct JSON request for it. For reference, the output I get in my terminal on executing the python script is given below.  I am quite new to this and I would be very thankful for any help from all of you.

> {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 1, 'result': {'qDocList': [{'qDocName': 'Test_2.qvf', 'qConnectedUsers': 0, 'qFileTime': 44188.190983796296, 'qFileSize': 851968, 'qDocId': 'C:\Users\mohdm\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Apps\Test_2.qvf', 'qMeta': {'hassectionaccess': False, 'encrypted': False}, 'qLastReloadTime': '2020-12-22T19:12:22.245Z', 'qTitle': 'Test_2', 'qThumbnail': {}}]}} 
>  {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 2, 'result': {'qReturn': {'qType': 'Doc', 'qHandle': 1, 'qGenericId': 'C:\Users\mohdm\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Apps\Test_2.qvf'}}, 'change': [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXx2H.png)} 
> {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 3, 'result': {'qReturn': {'qType': 'GenericObject', 'qHandle': 2, 'qGenericType': 'SheetList', 'qGenericId': '4b344780-a350-48db-8b65-27bb5a2c62b2'}}, 'change': [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXx2H.png)} 
>  {'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'id': 4, 'result': {'qLayout': {'qInfo': {'qId': '4b344780-a350-48db-8b65-27bb5a2c62b2', 'qType': 'SheetList'}, 'qMeta': {'privileges': ['read', 'update', 'delete', 'exportdata']}, 'qSelectionInfo': {}, 'qAppObjectList': {'qItems': [{'qInfo': {'qId': '8a0f6a01-ef89-4d65-821f-371c26208dcf', 'qType': 'sheet'}, 'qMeta': {'privileges': ['read', 'update', 'delete', 'exportdata'], 'title': 'Sheet_1', 'description': ''}, 'qData': {'rank': None, 'thumbnail': {'qStaticContentUrl': {}}, 'columns': 24, 'rows': 12, 'cells': [{'name': 'kfxNpV', 'type': 'auto-chart', 'col': 0, 'row': 0, 'colspan': 15, 'rowspan': 6, 'bounds': {'y': 0, 'x': 0, 'width': 62.5, 'height': 50}}, {'name': 'qHzmARQ', 'type': 'qlik-barplus-chart', 'col': 0, 'row': 6, 'colspan': 21, 'rowspan': 6, 'bounds': {'y': 50, 'x': 0, 'width': 87.5, 'height': 50}}, {'name': 'BXBQmw', 'type': 'auto-chart', 'col': 15, 'row': 0, 'colspan': 9, 'rowspan': 6, 'bounds': {'y': 0, 'x': 62.5, 'width': 37.5, 'height': 50}}], 'title':
> 'Sheet_1', 'description': ''}}]}}}} 
>  kfxNpV 
>  qHzmARQ 
>  BXBQmw

I had originally posted this question at [Qlik community](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-Sense-Integration-Extensions-APIs/Export-visualization-data-using-Qlik-Engine-JSON-API/m-p/1770208#M13665) as well but it didn't get a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this cases I'm usually "observing" Qlik's communication from the browser.

(in Chrome)

- open the app
- open the browser dev tools (press F12)
- navigate to "Network" (1)
- navigate to "WS" (2)
- press the required socket session (3)
- press "Messages" (4)
- check whats being send/received in the socket

(if you cant see the sockets in the Network tab just refresh the page)

[image]

Below is a Javascript/Node code that is exporting data for one object. (Im hardcoding the object ID in my case)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');

const enigma = require('enigma.js');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const schema = require('enigma.js/schemas/12.20.0.json');

const session = enigma.create({
    schema,
    url: 'ws://localhost:9076/app/engineData',
    createSocket: url => new WebSocket(url)
});

(async function () {
    // open new session
    let global = await session.open();

    // open the app
    let doc = await global.openDoc("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Documents\\Qlik\\Sense\\Apps\\Consumer_Sales.qvf");

    // get the required object
    let qObj = await doc.getObject("MEAjCJ");

    // OOXML - export the data in Excel (xlsx) format
    let data = await qObj.exportData("OOXML");

    // generate the full download link
    let downloadLink = `http://localhost:4848${data.qUrl}`;

    // download and save the file
    await axios.get(downloadLink, { responseType: "stream" })
        .then(response => {
            response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("export.xlsx"));
        });
})()
```

Official documentation for the ExportData method is [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2018/APIs/EngineAPI/services-GenericObject-ExportData.html)

**Update - Python code snippet**

The loop through the sheet objects can look like this:

```py
id = 5

list_of_charts = result_json['result']['qLayout']['qAppObjectList']['qItems'][0]['qData']['cells']
for chart in list_of_charts:

    obj_req = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "GetObject",
        "handle": app_req_handle,
        "params": [ chart["name"] ],
        "outKey": -1,
        "id": id
    }

    ws.send(json.dumps(obj_req))
    result = ws.recv()
    ws.send(json.dumps(obj_req))
    result = ws.recv()
    result_json = json.loads(result)
    # print(result_json)

    obj_req_handle = result_json['result']['qReturn']['qHandle']

    export_req = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "ExportData",
        "handle": obj_req_handle,
        "params": [ "OOXML" ],
        "outKey": -1,
        "id": 6
    }

    ws.send(json.dumps(export_req))
    result = ws.recv()
    ws.send(json.dumps(export_req))
    result = ws.recv()
    result_json = json.loads(result)

    downloadURL = "http://localhost:4848" + result_json["result"]["qUrl"]
    r = requests.get(downloadURL, allow_redirects=True)
    open('export_python_' + chart["name"] + '.xlsx', 'wb').write(r.content)

    id += 1
```

Comment: This is really amazing and thank you so much for your help @Stefan. I have written the equivalent of this code in Python due to the fact that I don't know node.js and struggle with it. The code is working with the JSON request with the only issue that it is generating 6 folders for 3 objects (basically running twice I guess). If it isn't an issue, can you please review the code I wrote in Python and give your feedback? Also let me know if I have to post the changed code in original question or on pastebin.

Comment: im not a python guy but ive ran your code and added the export piece (updated my answer with the snippet). In my case it was working fine - generated the correct number of files and its running only once

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stefan. I think the reason is that the url generated on a localhost machine points to the Exports directory found in "C:\Users\user_name\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Exports" which is where it accesses the file when you call it in the script using requests module. I presume that the Qlik Enterprise Server works on the same concept with the file being stored on the server instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Python, but I find that usually the hard part is getting the authentication right. Libraries like the ones that exist for JavaScript typically simplifies this a lot. Personally I tend to use C# for these kind of gadgets where the .NET SDK provides operators for doing the plumbing work for you. This is an example of what it could look like using these two nuget packages:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/QlikSense.NetSDK/
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/QlikSenseRestClient/

This code downloads xlsx files for all visualizations on the first sheet of the app.

```
var location = Location.FromUri(uri);
location.AsNtlmUserViaProxy();
var restClient = new RestClient(uri);
restClient.AsNtlmUserViaProxy();

using (var app = location.App(new AppIdentifier {AppId = appId}))
{
  var theSheet = app.GetSheets().First();
  var objs = theSheet.GetChildInfos().Select(info => app.GetGenericObject(info.Id));
  foreach (var o in objs)
  {
    var exportResult = o.ExportData(NxExportFileType.EXPORT_OOXML);
    var data = restClient.GetBytes(exportResult.Url);
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(o.Id + ".xlsx", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
    {
      writer.Write(data);
    }
  }
}
```